# Runing into error while predicting the model bulid in cv.glm on unbalanced test and training data

Tags: r, logistic-regression, cross-validation, multinomial

I have a model predicted using logistic regression using cv.glm on a training dataset and when I predict it on `testdata` and try to generate a confusion matrix it is throwing error.The classes of both train and `testdata` set are unbalanced.

Here are the dimensions of both test and train datasets. Both my `traindata` and `testdata` is from a big dataset of 1234 columns and 60 rows I split it randomly into two sets to check the sensitivity and specificity of classfication at the end.

```
> dim(traindata)
   40 1234
> dim(testdata)
[1]   20 1234
```

And this is what I tried.

```
Subtype   = factor(traindata$Subtype) 
CV=cv.glmnet(x=data.matrix(traindata),y=Subtype,standardize=TRUE,alpha=0,nfolds=3,family="multinomial")
response_predict=predict(CV, data.matrix(testdata),type="response")
predicted = as.factor(names(response_predict)[1:3][apply(response_predict[1:3], 1, which.max)])
```

Here it throws error as:

```
Error in apply(response_predict[1:3], 1, which.max) : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length
```

My question is with to proceed in such unbalanced dataset using `cv.glm`and how to get rid of the above mentioned error.
 Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unbalancedness has nothing to do with this error. First, `response_predict` is an array, not a matrix and not a data frame. For this reason, the last line should be

```
predicted <- as.factor(colnames(response_predict[, , 1])[1:3][apply(response_predict[, 1:3, 1], 1, which.max)])
```

That is, since we are dealing with a three dimensional array, we have three indices. Also `response_predict[1:3]` meant just three numbers rather than three array columns. And since `response_predict` is not a data frame, `names` were not going to give you the column names of it.

But actually all of that can be written, assuming that there are three possible classes, simply as

```
predicted <- as.factor(colnames(response_predict)[apply(response_predict, 1, which.max)])
```

which is much cleaner. I guess you are also aware that

```
predicted <- as.factor(predict(CV, data.matrix(testdata), type = "class"))
```

gives the same result as well.

Comment: @user1017373, does it answer your question?